# What happens to people stuck on a land border in North America?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, borders, removal

My German friend's US Visa expires, and he plans to travel to Canada, where he does not need a Visa.  However, he has overstayed in the past, and so I suspect he has a high change of being refused admission into Canada despite being on the Visa-exempt list.  There have been similar questions that for most countries say that he would be taken to a detention centre, who would figure out where he's admissible, and take him to that country.  I would like to know what would happen if this happens on the US side, vs. on the Canadian side.  Examples of per-country policies from previous posts:

- [U.K.](http://www.yarlswood.co.uk/) detention centre
- [France](http://www.cglpl.fr/2010/rapport-de-visite-du-centre-de-retention-administrative-de-toulouse-cornebarrieu/) detention centre
- [Germany](https://www.1a-jva.de/en/baden-wuerttemberg/jva-schwaebisch-gmuend.html) detention centre
- [Estonia](http://www.vangla.ee/et/asutused/viru-vangla) detention centre
- [Saudi Arabia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/55820/85359) holds you right there at the border crossing
- [Thailand](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/55790/85359) allows you to come back to the country as if you never left it
- [Brazil](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/decreto/Antigos/D86715.htm) lets you in, but you must stay in the same city, and within 3 days either leave or request asylum

Quite notably, US, Canada, and Mexico are not on the list.  Any experience?

Comment: The point of getting a Visa is to significantly enhance the likelihood of being admitted.  Was friend not truthful on his application?

Comment: @Alex What is your friend’s citizenship and which Canadian visa would he have? Or do you mean his country of citizenship is on the list allowed visa-free entry?

Comment: @Traveller He would get a Canadian tourist Visa.

Comment: @Johns-305 However, he has overstayed his Visa in the past, so he might be refused.

Comment: If he actually manages to get a temporary resident visa from Canada, it's very unlikely he will be refused entry. Of course, your post has absolutely no detail on _why_ you think he might be refused entry, so it's not really possible to give any specific advice.

Comment: That may certainly cause him to be refused a visa. But why would he then be refused entry, if he did manage to get a visa?

Comment: @MichaelHampton OK, fair enough, I don't know if that happens when travelling to Canada.  But definitely happens when traveling to the US (my German third cousin almost had that situation, when he transferred schools on   a valid F-1 visa, and didn't explain it to the border guard right, probably due to his English level).  So I've slightly modified the question, to ask the same thing in a different situation.  Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Does your question _now_ accurately reflect the situation? We might put a lot of work into answering the question, but if the true details are different, any answers may become wrong or useless.

Comment: @MichaelHampton So I guess what makes it confusing is, I have several friends in a similar situation, so I'd need an answer to this one way or another. Eg, the reasons they might not be admitted are different, and also for some the Canada to the US trip might be problematic, while for others it's the US to Canada (we're traveling there and back). But to avoid asking multiple similar questions, I've combined their situations into the 1 posted here. Let's say that I commit to keeping this question as is; if other issues come up, eg after applying for a tourist Visa, I'll post a separate question

Comment: @MichaelHampton Here is an example of someone refused entry with a valid visa: https://www.canadavisa.com/canada-immigration-discussion-board/threads/allowed-to-leave-canada-what-now.467463/
Example reason: overstaying a Visa in the US *after* the Canadian Visa was issued.  Since the US Visa was valid when the Canadian one was issued, a Canadian 3-year Visa was issued; however, then the person overstayed the US Visa, and so Canada can deny him even though his Canadian Visa is still valid.

Comment: The question doesn't really ask about the friend, but does pose it as part of the question - "Any experience [of what would happen at a North American land border]?" I just realised I probably could included Mexico in my answer, but it has been marked and upvoted nonetheless. What I'm wondering now is about this particular German guy. Where and what did he overstay - the US or Canada? What type of US visa does he have? The infinitive "expires" could be postulating or it could be a typo for "expired". Can @Alex clarify?

Comment: @Sam_Butler No, the German relative didn't overstay.  The reason he's under scrutiny is, because his F-1 Visa was given for attending college #1, but after attending he ended up transferring to college #2, and when he was entering the US he said he's going to college #2 before that college had a chance to transfer the I-20 from #1.  So they had a mismatch, and sent him back; he would've been fine if he said he's planning to attend #1 even though he actually would transfer to #2 before the next semester starts.

Comment: @Sam_Butler  So now he's in the US, but planning to leave for Canada on the day his F-1 expires, and reenter on an ESTA, until he gets another US Visa; but, he'd have to tell Canada that he's been refused entry to the US, so Canada might also give him an Allowed to Leave form.  I just wanted to simplify this story, so I posted the reason for a possible refusal from another friend of mine, who did overstay in the US, but might be able to get a Canadian Visa (we haven't tried yet).

Comment: Paperwork mismatch with no other issues will mitigate that, but he should get all the evidence of what happened, when, etc., and take it with him to the border. Honestly though, he should not leave on the day of expiry. More like a week before, just in case. ESTA only works on air travel too, and there should be a reasonable gap between departure and re-entry. If he wants to continue in education he's going to need another visa, so all of this would be best solved by flying to Germany, not driving to Canada.

Comment: He can reenter the US without a visa or ESTA, but it's still down to the CBP officer on the day: https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1132/~/citizen-of-visa-waiver-country%2C-wants-to-drive-into-u.s.-from-canada-or-mexico%2C

Comment: @Sam_Butler Good to know, this is a useful piece of immigration information.

Comment: You're welcome @Alex. I also found this regarding visa waiver reentry (not strictly the same as your relative's situation): https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/61835/38108

Comment: Please edit your question so that it clearly states all relevant information. For example, what do you mean by saying that his visa "expires"? Has it already expired? Is it due to expire some time in the future? Will that be before or after he goes to Canada? Everything that might be relevant needs to be in the question, so that people can find it without having to read this gigantic comment thread. Note that the majority of your post is actually an irrelevant list of links to what random countries do: that can all be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A person entering Canada at a land border (with the US, of course) would simply be returned to the US. There is no requirement for detention. An exception would be if the person [claimed asylum](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/news/2017/03/claiming_asylum_incanadawhathappens.html) at the border crossing. Canada does have immigration detention centres, subject to the [Immigration and Refugee Protection Act 2001](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/i-2.5/page-1.html).

In the United States, visas and entry clearance can have different expiry dates. Assuming the referenced expiry means that the person is no longer permitted to remain in the country (known as "out of status"), should US immigration authorities become aware, [the deportation process](https://www.usa.gov/deportation) may include detention at an ICE detention center.

If a person was already in Canada and attempted to cross the land border into the US without valid immigration status, they would be refused entry and returned to Canada.

Though the information is unverified, [this forum thread](https://www.canadavisa.com/canada-immigration-discussion-board/threads/coming-to-canada-from-usa-with-no-status-in-usa.472452/page-2) suggests that Canadian immigration officials will ask about an overstay in the US. An overstay in Canada, as the OP points out, is likely to affect any future application for entry clearance to Canada, even if a visa is not normally required.

Comment: I didn't include Mexico in the answer above, perhaps it can be edited when there's some more information. Certainly if you try to enter the US having overstayed, they'll apply a ban right there on the spot and send you back out the door, into Mexico. As far as I understand, you don't re-clear immigration on your way back, but this is only based on documentary footage, which doesn't always tell the whole story. I have seen that entering Canada by road, if denied entry, there's a loop back to the US side with no further checks.

Comment: The part "with no further checks" is false, e.g. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109183/denied-entry-to-canada-will-this-history-deny-me-entry-to-other-countries/125610#125610. I've been denied entry into Canada myself, and essentially what happened is, the Canadian border patrol walks me to the US side, to make sure that I get admitted into the US. I skip past all the cars waiting in line. He tells his US counterpart that they refused entry, and the US agent takes my passport, checks to make sure I'm in status, and no further checks (eg. baggage, declarations) were done after that.

Comment: As I mentioned, this was only based on documentary footage I have viewed, and your personal experience clearly trumps that. So there are some hoops to jump through, but for the most part there would be no issues **if in status**. Another reason why travelling on the day of expiry would be a bad idea.