# Being stuck between Russia and Turkmenistan at a sea border; what happens?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, sea-travel, deportation

The question is similar to [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/55755/what-happens-if-you-are-refused-entry-between-two-countries), but specifically focusing on sea travel between Russia and Turkmenistan.

Say you've got a Russian transit visa, but due to the ferry from Turkmenistan being severely delayed (it has no timetable in practice), it runs out by the time you arrive.

Then, obviously, you'll be sent back to Turkmenistan, which you now have no right to enter either (your visa has run out, so an exit cancellation is also probably not an option)

What will happen then, assuming your passport isn't from a nearby country and that country doesn't have a consulate in Turkmenistan?

Paying any bribes is out of the question.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the being sent back part? In general, deportation involves finding a country which will accept the subject.

Comment: @origimbo Caravanistan is a forum of people well-versed with the region, and apparently if you depart from country A and cannot enter B, you **will** be sent back to A no matter what happens afterwards

Comment: There are probably no practical differences between a sea border with limited options where to go and a land border, where you usually also only have two options (proceed or go back). At the Turkmen border I would bet that you can or must solve the problem with a bribe. From the other question, all answers except Gayot's (which is IMHO listing surreal and imaginary complications) would be valid for a generic question about sea borders as well. From first hand experience, exit cancellations, if applicable, seem to be a common solution for this problem.

Comment: You will become the new ferry captain and travel on the caspian sea forever ;-)

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I don't pay bribes, ever. Regarding exit cancellations, it's my understanding that it's only possible if you still have a valid visa. I've edited

Comment: Is this question specifically about Turkmenistan or more generic? A similar situation can occur with air travel.

Comment: @Relaxed Well at airports it's easier to swiftly put you on a flight anywhere, while at seaports your options are much more limited. And yeah, TUrkmenistan particularly came to my mind

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Edited the Q

Comment: @Coke Great, now all makes sense, but even if you don't like it (and I can understand that), I am pretty sure that the answer is that you will either be detained and harassed by the Turkmen immigration police for an indefinite period or you pay a bribe and they will simply readmit you. I will however let anyone with actual firsthand experience try to write a better answer :-)

Comment: Is there really a ferry between TKM and RUS?

Comment: @ach Yes, from Turkmenbashi to Olya

Comment: Wikivoyage more than indicates that you at the Caspian ferries may even have to bribe the captain or ship staff to be allowed off the ferry. Since you categorically refuse bribery as an option, I am not sure if this is just a hypothetical question and that the right 'answer' would be to tell you to avoid the situation or perhaps even the entire area completely. Even if we are not supposed to like it, there are areas of the world where bribery is so mundane that you neither as a local nor as a tourist will get through without.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo When I took the ferry Kazakhstan-Azerbaijan in July 2016, I got a free cabin for myself and a free meal, and I paid nothing for the trip besides the ticket fare (I would never have agreed to do so anyway, no matter the consequences)

Comment: @Coke The article on Caravanistan has changed recently due to some new information. But there was never any info on what would happen if you would land in Russia with an expired visa, only regarding the Baku-Turkmenbashi trip, and this is also changing it seems due to new Turkmen transit visas without a set duration (it seems, still awaiting more info). In general, I think the only way to solve this question is to turn off the computer and try it out for yourself. No way to figure it out in advance, very much dependent on the day and the person in front of you.

Comment: @NicolasB The Caspian Davy Jones.

Comment: How do you know they will allow you onto the ferry with an expiring visa? I would think they check visas beforehand?

Comment: @AussieJoe Like I said, delays, **massive** ones at that

Answer (score 5):

### What happens in cases of *force majeure* while travelling with a Transit Visa?

---

International law, as such, does not offer any binding *recommendations* on how to deal with such situations or what host measures host countries **must** do.

---

The present International Passport Recommendations **envolved** during the

- Paris Passport Convention 1920-10-21
- Geneva Passport Convention 1926-05-18

In general, Visitor and Transit multiple entry Visa's were issued once during the lifetime of a passport that was valid between 2 and 5 years.

This ended in the 1930's when one time entries became the norm. This situation, basicly, still exists today and leaving it up to each country to deside for themselfs if or how much of the *recommendations* it wishes to follow.

In 1947 further *recommendations* were agreed to in the area of Aviation (ICAO) which can be seen as a continuation of the Paris and Geneva Conventions since it deals with general travel regulations and Passport standards.

---

In the case of the given situation between Russia and Turkmenistan, there is no **binding** protocol that both countries **must** follow

- such as the **usage of common sense**

since Convention recommendations are mostly based on a *minimal* consensus.

The **Annex 9** sample below shows that all parties have agreed that in-transit passengers may be allowed to leave the airport

- but does not **require** a country to issue a needed emergency visa

National regulations implementing **Temporary Landing Permit** (for Airplanes to land in a country)

- can refuse such a permit based on a negative nationality list or even in cases of a allowed national, but not when that national is of a specific national origin

So in the end, each country can decide how to deal with a specific situation (assuming it wishes to deal with at all).

Never assume that **common sense** will prevail.

---

Annex 9 - ICAO (International Civil Aviation Organization)

> **P. Emergency assistance/entry visas in cases of force majeure**
>    
>   3.72 **Recommended Practice**.— Contracting States should establish measures for authorizing temporary entry for a passenger or crew member who does not possess the required entry visa prior to arrival, due to diversion or delay of a flight for reasons of force majeure.
>    
>   3.73 Contracting States shall establish measures whereby in-transit passengers who are unexpectedly delayed due to a flight cancellation or delay may be allowed to leave the airport for the purpose of taking accommodations.
>    
>   3.74 **Recommended Practice**.— In emergency situations resulting from force majeure, Contracting States, aircraft operators and airport operators should give priority assistance to those passengers with medical needs, unaccompanied minors and persons with disabilities who have already commenced their journeys.
>    
>  
>   3.75 **Recommended Practice**.— Contracting States should establish measures to permit the departure from, or the transit through, their territories of passengers holding valid air travel reservations even if their visas have expired due to flight delays resulting from force majeure.
>    
>   3.76 **Recommended Practice**.— Contracting States should establish measures to facilitate the entry of personnel required to be deployed at short notice to assist passengers whose flights have been disrupted as a result of force majeure.     
>   3.77 **Recommended Practice**.— In cases of flight delays or diversions resulting from force majeure, Contracting States should establish measures to permit the transit through their territories of passengers holding valid air travel reservations but who do not possess the required entry

6 points listed, 5 of which are only recommendations

- should not be considered a **binding** international law

---

An artical at **Schengen Visa Info** describes a situation that happened on the 2nd of August 2016

[49 passengers, mostly Turks, without Schengen visa stuck in Vienna airport](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/news/49-passengers-mostly-turks-without-schengen-visa-stuck-vienna-airport/)

> The incident occurred after the British Airways Flight BA677 between Istanbul and London was forced to make an emergency landing due to a breakdown in Austrian capital Vienna on Friday.
>    
>   British Airways, the owner of the plane, booked hotels for passengers to stay the night in the city, but 49 of the passengers were not allowed to leave the airport because they didn’t have Schengen visas.
>    
>   Authorities of the airway company booked hotels in the city for the 249 passengers but the Austrian police didn’t allow 49 of them to stay in the hotels, forcing them to stay stuck in Vienna airport instead.
>    
>   One of the passengers, Yusuf Sami Kamadan, a correspondent for Turkish state channel TRT, tweeted about the situation on the night. He described how, **“We were treated against international law, I will sue the British Airways.”**

**Note**:
Beware of people who makes such statements **without** stating explicitly which international law is meant.

In this case, British Airways **cannot** be charged because the Austrian Border Police do not follow the *recommendation* stated in the ICAO Annex 9, 3.72.

---

**References**:

- [Pdf Geneva Passport Convention 1926-05-18](https://biblio-archive.unog.ch/Dateien/CouncilMSD/C-423-M-156-1926-VIII_EN.pdf)

  - Paris Convention 1920-10-21 Resolution

    - Pdf pages 152-156
  - 1926-05-18 Final Act - Recommemdations

    - Pdf pages 163-168
- [Pdf Annex 9 - ICAO (International Civil Aviation Organization)](https://www.icao.int/WACAF/Documents/Meetings/2018/FAL-IMPLEMENTATION/an09_cons.pdf)

  - **P. Emergency assistance/entry visas in cases of force majeure**

    - Pdf Page 39
- [Pdf Instructions relating to grant of Visa to crew of non-scheduled airlines and chartered flights and issue of **Temporary Landing Permit**](https://mha.gov.in/PDF_Other/TLP_050913.pdf)