# What happens if I'm refused at the border but am unable to return to my point of departure?

Tags: removal

This is a hypothetical question that came up in discussion.

Consider a situation where I am in country A. I take a flight to country B, and am refused admission at the border. However I am not allowed back to country A -- maybe I only had a single entry visa, or I used up my visa-free allowance; either way I can't be just put on the next flight back from the same airline.

In this case, how would the removal work? Would they send me back to my home country? Would they force the airline to take me somewhere directly that I *am* allowed to enter? (And if the airline I came on doesn't fly anywhere from B to where I can go, will the airline need to pay for a ticket on a other airline to somewhere I can enter?)

---

For a concrete example: a US citizen flies from Spain to the UK after using up his/her 90-out-of-180 days in the Schengen zone. The immigration officers in London refuse entrance for whatever reason. What happens to our poor Yankee friend?

Comment: Hopefully he doesn't end up like Nasseri https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehran_Karimi_Nasseri

Comment: The guidance covers how removals work. In the case you described, the passenger would most likely get removed to Spain because he's not in political danger there. The UK does not participate in Schengen and what happens to the American when he gets there is (as the Brits say) hard cheese.

Comment: Not a duplicate, that question is about a land border.

Comment: This one might work as a canonical for the OP's question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52025/airline-policy-when-a-passenger-is-refused-entry-in-both-departure-and-arrival-c

Comment: I am pretty sure we have exactly the same question somewhere, but I can't find it. Short answer: Legal details depend on the country you are flying to, but the airline is usually required to bring you to a country, in which you are allowed to enter. It does not have to be the country you originally come from. Most airlines have in their terms and conditions that you are liable for any costs related to such transport, so wether the airline can put you on one of their own flights or they have to buy you a ticket on another airline, the bill will eventually land at your desk.

Comment: I know of an Iranian that was caught in Trinidad traveling on a well-forged Canadian passport that had gotten him transit through several other countries on the way there. They checked the document only because they found it curious that he spoke neither English nor French. He spent 2 years in jail there while they figured out how to send him home, by which time his English was pretty good.

Comment: If the passenger is removed to Spain, could Spain reject him and bounce him back to the UK?